# Validate Form - Multiple Error Messages Appearing

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to write a pure JavaScript form validation that will add an error message next to the `label` elements if the `input` is empty.

The confirmEmail `input` gets an additional error message if it does not match the email `input`

My problem is that if you hit the submit button when all fields are empty, then put a value into the `email` input but leave confirmEmail empty and hit submit again, both error messages will appear next to the confirmEmail's label.  The ideal result would be that confirmEmail only has text that says "Email does not match"

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R5e2T/

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="theForm">
  <div>
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="first" value="" />
  </div>

  <div> 
    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" name="last" value="" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <br> 
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="confirmEmail">Confirm Email:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="confirmEmail" name="confirmEmail" value="" />
  </div>     

  <button type="button" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function validate () {  
  var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm'),
      firstName = document.getElementById('firstName'),
      lastName = document.getElementById('lastName'),
      email = document.getElementById('email'),
      confirmEmail = document.getElementById('confirmEmail'),
      label = theForm.getElementsByTagName('label'),
      input = theForm.getElementsByTagName('input'),
      inputLength = input.length;

  // Remove any spans that may have been added by the next for loop
  for (var x = 0; x < inputLength; x++) {
     var currLbl = label[x];  
     if ( currLbl.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span').length > 0 ) {
        var span = currLbl.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];          
        removeElement(span);
    }
  }

  // Error checking for the form.
  // Add error message next to any element that has a blank value.
  for (var i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {
    // innerText for IE, textContent for other browsers
    var labelText = label[i].innerText || label[i].textContent;
    var currLabel = label[i];
    var text = document.createTextNode( labelText + ' cannot be empty');

    if ( input[i].value === '' ) {
        currLabel.parentNode.style.color = 'red';
        currLabel.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', ' <span>cannot be empty</span>');

    }
    else if ( input[i].value !== '') {
        currLabel.parentNode.style.color = '';
    }
  }

  // Test to see if confirmEmail is equal to email.
  // If not add a warning message next to confirmEmail's label
  if (confirmEmail.value !== email.value) {
    var labelElement = confirmEmail.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label')[0]
    labelElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', ' <span>Email does not match</span>');
    labelElement.parentNode.style.color = 'red';
  }

  // Test to make sure all inputs have a value,
  // and that confirmEmail equals email.    
  if (firstName.value !== '' && lastName.value !== '' && email.value !== '' && confirmEmail.value !== '' && email.value === confirmEmail.value) {
    alert("Submitted!!!");
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

};

// Remove Element function
function removeElement(node) {
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
(function () {
  var button = document.getElementById('submitButton');
  button.addEventListener('click', validate, false);
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**I forked your fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/AdyzH/2/)
What I did was to use `innerHtml` and just replace the text of the label, instead of creating new span-nodes and appending them to the document.

I store the original label, like "E-Mail" in a dataset variable, so that I can reset the label later.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm not even sure why I thought about adding an extra span tag.

Answer (score 1):

[Another solution](http://jsfiddle.net/R5e2T/13/) is to add this before you add the "Email doensn't match" message:

```
var oldSpan = labelElement.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
removeElement(oldSpan);
```

An even better solution would be to check for `confirmEmail` matching `email` before checking for empty fields and do not add the "cannot be empty" message if another error message has been added already.